# Is it possible to declare one jQuery validation for two forms with different POST data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have combined my `jQuery Validate` code for two forms like this,

```
$("#formregister,#updateform").validate({

  rules: {
    captcha: {
      required: true,
      remote: {
        url: "application/modules/customer_account/captcha/check.php",
        type: "post"
      }
    },

    //emails
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      minlength: 2,
      remote: {
        url: "checkemail.php", // temp -  this should be module/controller/function
        type: "post",
        data: {
          email: function() {
            return $('#formregister:input[name="email"],#updateform:input[name="email"]').val();
          }
        }
      }
    },
    //passwords
    user_password: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 6
    },
    repassword: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 6,
      equalTo: "#user_password"
    },
    // billing
    bill_company_name: {
      required: true
    },
    bill_first_name: {
      required: true
    },
    bill_last_name: {
      required: true
    },
    bill_address: {
      required: true
    },
    bill_city: {
      required: true
    },
    bill_state: {
      required: true
    },
    bill_zip_code: {
      required: true
    },
    bill_country: {
      required: true
    },
    bill_phone: {
      required: true
    },
    ship_company_name: {
      required: true
    },
    ship_first_name: {
      required: true
    },
    ship_last_name: {
      required: true
    },
    ship_address: {
      required: true
    },
    ship_city: {
      required: true
    },
    ship_state: {
      required: true
    },
    ship_zip_code: {
      required: true
    },
    ship_country: {
      required: true
    },
    ship_phone: {
      required: true
    },
    businessType: {
      required: true
    },
    businessValue: {
      required: true
    },
    businessLicense: {
      required: true
    },
    aboutUsHear: {
      required: true
    },
    aboutUsValue: {
      required: true
    }

  },


  // messages
  messages: {
    captcha: {
      required: "Enter the characters as seen on the image above.",
      remote: $.format("Please provide Correct captcha!")
    },
    email: {
      required: "Please enter valid email address",
      minlength: $.format("Enter at least {0} characters"),
      remote: $.format("{0} is already registered!")
    },
    password: {
      required: "Please Provide a password",
      rangelength: $.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
    },
    repassword: {
      required: "Repeat your password",
      minlength: $.format("Enter at least {0} characters"),
      equalTo: "Enter the same password as above"
    }
  },

  //on form submitting
  submitHandler: function(form) { // for demo
    form.submit();
  },
  // field messages
  success: function(label) {
    var name = label.attr('for');
    var messages = new Array(
      "Looks good1!",
      "You got it1!",
      "is Ok1!");
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

    label.text(name + ' ' + messages[num]).addClass("valid");
    label.select(name + ' ' + messages[num]).addClass("valid");

  }
});
```

As you can see there are two forms, `#formregister` and `#updateform`. For `#formregister` I only need `email` post data while for `#updateform` I need `email` and `uid` post data which is not shown here in this code. When I tried to submit each of the forms, the POST data is `undefined`, why is that? Is there something wrong with how I concatenate it? Is there a way I could still follow these single validate initialization and will not give undefined post data? Thanks.

Comment: @nbanic Without knowing how form looks like and how they share inputs it is impossible to help you. Please paste forms also.

Comment: @r.piesnikowski I only edited the question, I am not the author :)

Comment: @r.piesnikowski thanks man, I got the answer. However I am not quite sure if these goes for everybody. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solution applies to everybody but notice here on this part of my `jQuery Validate`

```
   data: {
      email: function() {
        return $('#formregister:input[name="email"],#updateform:input[name="email"]').val();
      }
    }
```

, notice the form ids and the element it needs to find is not separated by even a single `space`. I edited my form, a lucky edit I guess, and it worked. What I did not understood is why did a mere `space` mattered for this scenario. Anyway, that solved it. Thanks everybody.